# A error about "Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd" in c program under linux environment

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

[Edit1:]

For the seqName, I declare it as a global parameter at the beginning of the file as

**char seqName[20];**

[Edit2:]

Aren't those number of passing to the program during the actual execution? I got the following message just by using the valgrind tool. The command I input is:

**jl@ubuntu:~/work/dsr_analysis$ valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./test**

[Edit3:]

Sorry, since I am a new user of Valgrind, when I use it, I only typing the command in Edit2.

However, my program dose have some command-line parameters.

Therefore, I think I'd better to debug my program by the new command:

**valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./test foreman.cif 352 288**

---

There is a piece of my program:

```
height = atoi(argv[3]);

width = atoi(argv[2]);

sprintf(seqName,"%s", argv[1]);

// strcpy(seqName, argv[1]);
```

After compiling it, a exe file test is generated, then I use Valgrind to check it.
Then I got the following message, however I cannot understand what it tends to tell me.
Can anyone provide some kind help, Thanks.

**jl@ubuntu:~/work/dsr_analysis$ valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./test**

> ==28940== Memcheck, a memory error detector
>
> ==28940== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
>
> ==28940== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX;
>
> rerun with -h for copyright info
>
> ==28940== Command: ./test
>
> ==28940==
>
> ==28940== Invalid read of size 1
>
> ==28940==    at 0x40260CA: strcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:311)
>
> ==28940==    by 0x804A5C6: main (me_search.c:1428)
>
> ==28940==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
>
> ==28940==
>
> ==28940==
>
> ==28940== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
>
> ==28940==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
>
> ==28940==    at 0x40260CA: strcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:311)
>
> ==28940==    by 0x804A5C6: main (me_search.c:1428)
>
> ==28940==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
>
> ==28940==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
>
> ==28940==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
>
> ==28940==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
>
> ==28940==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
>
> ==28940==
>
> ==28940== HEAP SUMMARY:
>
> ==28940==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==28940==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
>
> ==28940==
>
> ==28940== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
>
> ==28940==
>
> ==28940== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>
> ==28940== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 8)1 contexts 
>   (suppressed: 13 from 8)

1 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 8)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really haven't posted clear enough code to be sure, but if you call your executable with no command-line parameters, then `argv[1]` will contain a `NULL` pointer, and `argv[2]`, `argv[3]` etc. will contain undefined values.

**Edit:** You need to provide the program with parameters on the valgrind command line (I guess - I don't use valgrind myself). Something like:

```
valgrind ... ./test foo bar zod
```

And BTW, calling an executable `test` is a bad idea on Linux/Unix as it is very easy to get confused with the shell built-in of the same name

Comment: I will not stand for this. General Zod must be argued before the mere peasants `foo` and `bar`!

Comment: *I* always thought the sequence went "foo, bar, baz, quux"

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you should check:

1) Make sure that you are being passed the correct number of parameters by checking the value of `argc`.

2) Make sure that you have used `malloc()` to allocate enough space in `seqName` before attempting the `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you check actual number of arguments passed to your program? (`argc`)

If your program gets less than 3 arguments, and you try to acess `argv[1..3]` - you'll get segmentation faults, and other unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: There is no such thing in C as a NULL pointer exception, or any kind of exception, come to that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is this: `sprintf(seqName,"%s", argv[1])`

And what you actually want is `sprintf((strcat(seqName,"%s"), argv[1])` judging your code.

What it tries to do here is pass the value of the expression "%s" to be interpreted in the format. That value is specifically a char pointer to a '%' in static memory with a 's' next to it, and then a '\0'.

Edit, oh wait, nevermind, I see it's sprintf, not printf. Then it's probably the argcount

Edit2: Also, is seqName properly initialized and allocated?